# Lookahead in BigQuery Regexp

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

It seems like BigQuery regexp does not support lookahead functionality.
Does anybody know if this is correct, and if it is, is there any plan to support it sometime soon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BigQuery regex uses [re2](https://code.google.com/p/re2/).  It appears that there are no plans to add lookaround assertions (or backreferences, incidentally) to re2.  As far as I can tell, the hard limit on adding them is finding an adequate implementation that maintains linear running time, as guaranteed by re2.

In my opinion, though, the point at which you add backreferences or lookaround assertions to a regex is a really good time to revisit whether regex is really the right tool for the job.

Comment: what would be a good tool to do this? sorry I am quite new to this.

Comment: Other tools may mean that you can write regex that does not use the lookahead. Perhaps your matching does not actually require lookahead. For particular purposes, you could mix other BigQuery functionality. It would feel like a hack, but consider the regex `:(?:.(?!:))+$` that looks ahead for stuff after the last `:`. It could be written without regex as `ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(`string`, '::'))[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)]` in SQL.