# BigQuery regex lookbehind / lookahead workaround?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

Doing ETL with BigQuery, I aim at cleaning up some text codes:

The standard syntax of these codes is ABC D123 or ABCD D123 (a group of letters, followed by a space, followed by another letter, followed by a group of numbers).

Some numbers however have a O (capital letter) entered instead of a number 0 (zero). These errors are found at the end of the number sequence: so ABC D56O should become ABC D560.

I tried using `regexp_replace()` using a lookbehind assertion such as `(?<=[0-9])O`.

However, it seems the [r2 library](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) isn't handling lookbehind, [see this post from 2013 for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090321/lookahead-in-bigquery-regexp).

So is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These errors are found at the end of the number sequence

Why not just simply replace `O` (capital letter) to `0` (zero) when it is at the end of the code - as it is in below example

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 'ABC D123' code union all
  select 'ABCD D123' union all
  select 'ABC D56O' 
)
select code, 
  regexp_replace(code, r'O$', '0') as fixed_code
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

In case if `O` can be found in any position where `0` expected - use below

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 'ABC D123' code union all
  select 'ABCD D123' union all
  select 'ABC D56O' union all
  select 'ABC DO56' union all
  select 'ABC D5O6' 
)
select code, 
  regexp_extract(code, r'[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]') || 
  replace(regexp_extract(code, r'[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z](.+)'), 'O', '0') as fixed_code
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]